# Diophantine Equation in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> I would like to know how to solve $2x^2 - y^{14} = 1$ in integers.

I've transformed it into $(y^7 - 1)^2 + (y^7 + 1)^2 = (2x)^2$ and I have stopped here.

Comment: There is the obvious solution $x=y=1$, and any other solutions would have be connected to solutions of the negative Pell's equation $z^2-2x^2=-1$, but I think it is extremely unlikely that any of those (other than 1) would give a $z$ value which is a perfect 7th power.

Comment: No, it is (2x)^2.

Comment: How about to use Pythagorean Triples? What would we have?

Comment: We would need a Pythagorean triple in which the 2 shorter sides differ by exactly 2 - that might be a basis for proving there are no other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Negate each side of the equation:
\begin{align}
y^{14} - 2x^2 = -1.
\end{align}
This is the negative Pell equation in $y^7$ and $x$, which is easy to find solutions for. Then simply look at the solutions for which $y$ is integral.

see [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) for more information.

Comment: "jerkoff", I tried using Pell's Equation but I couldn't obtain the solutions. Please, post your solution if you can.

Comment: $x=1, y=1$ is one solution, I am not sure about any others.

Comment: "simply look at the solutions for which $y$ is integral." As there are infinitely many solutions to look at, how do you propose to determine which ones are integral?

Comment: y has to be 0 or 1 (mod 7).

Comment: I looked at a related issue: (xn)^2-2(yn)^2=1 (later to be investigated for xn=z^7). The lowest solution is the pair x1=3 and y1=2.  I look at the families of solutions x1,x2,x3 … etc. and y1,y2,y3 with x2=(2(x1)^2+1) and y2=2x1y1  where (x2)^2-2(y2)^2=1. After the first two x solutions x1 and x2 (3 and 19) I get x3=723 =2 (mod 7). From here on, all solutions for x are 2 (mod 7) since 2*2^2+1=9=2 (mod 7). But our equation implies that x^2 must equal 2y^2+1 which can never be 4 (mod 7).Since x^7=x mod (7) we cannot have x^14-2y^2=1 for this family. X=3 and 19 obviously will not do either.